# g++ 4.6 issue no <bits/c++config.h> file as required by the header cstring

Tags: c++, g++, clang, cstring, clang++

There is no file called `bits/c++config.h` in the c++ include directory which is required by the `cstring` header file. But when I include the the header `cstring` and compile with `g++`, it does not give me error. The problem occurred when I tried to compile the program with `clang++`  compiler in the following way.

```
$clang++ -cc1 -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/c++/4.6.1 -I/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6.1 -I/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu -I opt_149739_build/include hello.cpp

In file included from /media/space/hello.cpp:2:
In file included from /media/space/opt_149739_build/include/clang/Driver/Driver.h:13:
In file included from /media/space/opt_149739_build/include/clang/Basic/Diagnostic.h:17:
In file included from /media/space/opt_149739_build/include/clang/Basic/DiagnosticIDs.h:18:
In file included from /media/space/opt_149739_build/include/llvm/ADT/StringRef.h:14:
/usr/include/c++/4.6.1/cstring:42:10: fatal error: 'bits/c++config.h' file not found
#include <bits/c++config.h>
```

I am using g++ 4.6.1 on Ubuntu 11.04

What went wrong?

Comment: could provides more details, like for instance : which version of gcc do you use ? on which OS ? and what is your gcc command line ?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The file `bits/c++config.h` is the platform specific include relative to the current compiler, so it is hidden in another directory, searched by default by g++, but not by clang++, as it seems.

In my machine, running `locate c++config.h` gives the following (relevant) files:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.6/i686-linux-gnu/64/bits/c++config.h
/usr/include/c++/4.6/i686-linux-gnu/bits/c++config.h
```

The first one is for 64-bits and the second one for 32-bits.

So just add `-I/usr/include/c++/4.6/i686-linux-gnu` or `-I/usr/include/c++/4.6/i686-linux-gnu/64` or whatever you need for your platform.

Comment: yes i found out it is there in the same directory what you got. thanks

Comment: If you don't have the appropriate c++config.h for your architecture, install libstdc++-devel from your repository.

Comment: in some cases this might not be enough: sometimes you need -I/usr/include/c++/4.6/i686-linux-gnu/c++/4.6 I use -I/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/c++/4.7/ for my machine and 4.7 version of gcc and it all works

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same problem while cross-compiling, the problem was solved after installing libstdc++-10-dev for arm. If you are not cross-compiling then you can try installing latest libstdc++ pkg.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libstdc++-10
```

Then you may run into a header error: ' asm/errno.h' file not found. Just install gcc-multilib for this.

```
sudo apt install gcc-multilib
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be related to how clang++ search its headers files.

You'll find a sample patch of how they fix it for fedora 15, 4 months ago, [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.compilers.clang.devel/17385).

See this [red hat bugzilla post](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=680644) for more info.

Comment: While installing clang I did edit the Frontend/InitHeaderSearch.cpp file to include the required directories to address the problem. Still I got this error. For now, I have added all the required paths in my CMakeLists.txt to address this issue.